# Auto delete comment if Contains

Tags: comments, hooks, spam

How to Auto-Delete comment if contains certain string?

i tried with this but not work:

```
add_action( 'transition_comment_status', 'my_approve_comment_callback', 10, 3 );

function my_approve_comment_callback( $new_status, $old_status, $comment ) {
    if (strpos($comment->comment_content, 'dog') !== false) {
            wp_delete_comment( $comment->comment_ID, true );
    }       
}
```

I have also tried with:

```
wp_list_comments('callback=better_comment');

function better_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
    if (strpos($comment->comment_content, 'dog') !== false) {
            wp_delete_comment( $comment->comment_ID, true );
    }   
}
```

Nothing work =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use 'comment_post' action for this purpose, it is fired when the comment is saved in database:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'my_comment_post_callback', 10, 3);

function my_comment_post_callback($comment_id, $comment_approved, $commentdata) {
    if (strpos($commentdata['comment_content'], 'dog') !== false) {
        $post_url = get_permalink($commentdata['comment_post_ID']);
        wp_delete_comment($comment_id, true);
        wp_redirect($post_url);
        exit;
    }       
}
```

Comment: It work but when post comment with dog return white page, why?

Comment: White page with this link "wp-comments-post.php#comment-"

Comment: I have updated the example. When you delete the comment while it was processed for the first time, WordPress doesn't know how to return to the post this comment belongs too. If you want to redirect somewhere else, change the redirect URL.

Comment: How could this be updated to accept multiple strings/words?